# webp image doesn't appear in the safari , iphone etc

Tags: image, webp

I use webp image . But image doesn't appear in the safari , iphone , internet explorer etc.
there is html picture tag on the html for this.
But i have to use two image as different extension .
for example image.webp and image.jpg.

```
<picture>
    <source type="image/webp" srcset="/frontend/images/blog/image.webp">
    <source type="image/jpeg" srcset="/frontend/images/blog/image.jpg">
    <img src="/frontend/images/blog/1572878193.jpg" alt="My Image">
</picture>
```

does tag install these two image or one.
if install these two images , my website will run as slowly.